# Find $\lim(\int_{0}^{1}\left((1-t)a+tb)^x)dt\right)^{(1/x)}$ when $x\to0$ and $x\to\infty$.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, exponential-function

My first step was to do $$(1-t)a+tb=u$$ so the integral will be $$\frac{1}{b-a}\int_{a}^{b}u^xdx=\frac{b^{x+1}-a^{x+1}}{(b-a)(x+1)}$$
then we need to find $$\lim\left(\frac{b^{x+1}-a^{x+1}}{(b-a)(x+1)}\right)^{(1/x)}$$
and I haven't made any progress from that point.
I tried to apply logarithms and Stolz-Cesàro Theorm, but none of that worked for me.
I accept any help to simplify this limit and find your value.
Thanks for attention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clearly $b>a>0$. By LH'opital's Rule, one has
\begin{eqnarray}
&&\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac1x\ln\left(\frac{b^{x+1}-a^{x+1}}{(b-a)(x+1)}\right)\\
&=&\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\ln(b^{x+1}-a^{x+1})-\ln(b-a)-\ln(x+1)}x\\
&=&\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{b^{x+1}\ln b-a^{x+1}\ln a}{b^{x+1}-a^{x+1}}-\frac1{x+1}\\
&=&\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\ln b-(\frac{a}{b})^{x+1}\ln a}{1-(\frac{a}{b})^{x+1}}=\ln b
\end{eqnarray}
and hence
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\frac{b^{x+1}-a^{x+1}}{(b-a)(x+1)}\right)^{(1/x)}=b.$$
For the other one,
\begin{eqnarray}
&&\lim_{x\to0}\frac1x\ln\left(\frac{b^{x+1}-a^{x+1}}{(b-a)(x+1)}\right)\\
&=&\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\ln(b^{x+1}-a^{x+1})-\ln(b-a)-\ln(x+1)}x\\
&=&\lim_{x\to0}\frac{b^{x+1}\ln b-a^{x+1}\ln a}{b^{x+1}-a^{x+1}}-\frac1{x+1}\\
&=&\frac{b\ln b-a\ln a}{b-a}-1\\
\end{eqnarray}
and hence
$$\lim_{x\to0}\left(\frac{b^{x+1}-a^{x+1}}{(b-a)(x+1)}\right)^{(1/x)}=\frac{e^{\frac{b\ln b-a\ln a}{b-a}}}{e}.$$